# Is there a way to reduce topic creation time in google cloud pubsub?

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I used the createTopic function of the google cloud pub/sub, but when I measured the time, I found that it took quite a long time. Is there any way to improve this?

```
const start = Date.now()
;[topic] = await this.pubSub.createTopic(topicName)
const end = Date.now()
console.log(`TOPIC CREATION TOOK ${end - start}ms`)
// TOPIC CREATION TOOK 19054ms
```

It takes 15 seconds if it takes less and 30 seconds if it takes more.
I hope it comes out less than 1000ms. thank you.

Comment: You can't compress this time. The solution is to create the PubSub topic in advance. What's your use case that require to create a PubSub topic on the fly and with a low latency?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Thank you! I was just wondering if there was a setting that could speed things up.